# How to choose a Journal name in MDPI LaTeX template?

Tags: templates, journal-publishing, mdpi

**At first, I want to clarify that this question is *not* related to the bibliography or references.**

I've downloaded [the latex template of MDPI](https://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex).

I am able to work with the LaTeX template and my journal manuscript is ready. The only problem is I'm unable to edit the footnote where it says *Submitted to **Journal Not Specified**, pages...*

I know that the MDPI may edit it themselves after I submit the manuscript. However, I want to submit it as a perfectly formatted manuscript. I tried to search the footnotes keyword in all the available `.tex` files `(template.tex, journalnames.tex, and mdpi.cls)`, however, it went on vain. I want to submit my manuscript to the ***Sensors*** and I can see its name and other details in the `journalnames.tex` file. However, I could not edit the footnotes for the ***Sensors***.

Comment: Do not forget to submit the preprint to https://engrxiv.org/ or https://arxiv.org/ :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to pass the corresponding option to the `\documentclass`. You said yourself you found the entry of the Sensors journal in the `journalnames.tex` file:

```
\DeclareOption{sensors}{\gdef\@journal{sensors}\gdef\@journalshort{Sensors}\gdef\@journalfull{Sensors}\gdef\@doiabbr{s}\gdef\@ISSN{1424-8220}}
```

so you can see that the declared option name is `sensors` (all lower case), so you have to use:

```
\documentclass[sensors]{mdpi}
```

Comment: You were faster.... lol

Comment: It worked. I've one more issue. I can see `\corres` to add the corresponding author in the template. However, when I compile the file, I cannot see it on the manuscript.  `\corres` is not commented in the latex file. Why is it not working?

Comment: @santobedi I was checking now a paper I've published there, and it looks like you need the `moreauthors` option to get `\corres` to show up.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I fixed it. Instead of `\documentclass[sensors]{Definitions/mdpi}`, I used `\documentclass[sensors,article,submit,moreauthors,pdftex,10pt,a4paper{Definitions/mdpi}]`  and everything required showed up.

Comment: @santobedi Recheck that `\documentclass` specification. I highly doubt you pasted it correctly here.